# Make Math.random return positive odd integer

Tags: javascript

Fairly basic question but I need something that can make `var n = Math.random()` to give me "n" as a **positive odd integer**
How do I do this?

Comment: var x = Math.random() * theRangeTop | 1;   will give only odd integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generate an integer in the appropriate range, multiply it by 2, then add 1.

For example if you want odd integers between 1 and 99 then generate a random integer in the range 0 to 49.

**Related**

- [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

Answer (score 1):

Generate the number in desired range and **then make it `ODD` if it is not.**

```
    //<-Generate the number between 0 to MAX 
    int randNum=   (int)(Math.random()*MAX_VALUE); 
    if(randNum %2 == 0){//generated number is even
       if(randNum == MAX_VALUE){
         randNum  = randNum -1 ;
       }else{
         randNum  = randNum +1 ;
       }
    }
```

Now the random number is an odd number within the range